Invokehttp processor broke with error java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
Team, Today i saw a strange behavior in NiFi v1.23.0 InvokeHTTP processor, all of sudden it's start throwing error in "invokehttp.java.exception.message" and its point out that "Nifi Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty".
After, just restart the NiFi service, processor runs again it job smoothly.
can anyone suggest the fix.
